# Como salvar <textarea> no HTML?

Tags: textarea

Quando eu rodo o javascript, roda normalmente, a minha duvida era, como que eu pego o código agora dessa tabela que o script mudou.

Comment: Você quer salvar o texto digitado na textarea onde? so html creio que nao seja possivel. No minimo você vai precisar de javascript, mesmo não creio que seja possivel salvar dados na maquina direto do javascript.

Comment: Salvar onde? ..

Comment: Tenho esse html ae, só que salvo no meu pc. Eu abro ele no meu navegador, como que eu boto o botão salvar para ele salvar no html do meu pc.

Comment: Mas que HTML do teu PC?

Comment: <html>
<table><textarea>Tester</textarea></table>
</html>

Comment: Você quer fazer um botão para salvar ou apenas colocar esse texto no textarea?

Comment: Salvar onde? Essa é a questão!

Comment: Para salvar o conteúdo digitado no textarea você precisa primeiramente coloca-lo dentro de um form e submeter o envio através de um input type submit, como sugestão de leitura recomendo o seguinte link: http://tableless.com.br/formulario-basico-em-8-minutos/. Sobre como salvar é relativo, você quer fazer salvo em um arquivo txt, banco de dados...?

Comment: talvez ele queira usar algo como o local storage do HTML5 http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: apenas colocar esse texto no textarea

Answer (score 3):

Usando o **Local Storage** do **HTML5** você consegue salvar o texto do textarea localmente, assim mesmo q você feche o arquivo os valores estarão lá.

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <html><table><textarea id='result'>Escreva aqui seu lembrete</textarea></table></html>
    <button onClick="salvar()">Salvar</button>

    <script>

    function salvar() {
        // Check browser support
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            // Store
            localStorage.setItem("text", document.getElementById("result").value);

        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Local Storage não suportado";
        }
    }

    // Retrieve
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("text");
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ndnu2nn/